# Pygame logo doesn't change

Tags: python, pygame, icons

So I tried to change the icon for pygame and it doesn't change, just shows the default snake. I tried it with another logo and it works, but I can't figure out why that one works and the one I want doesn't. Can someone help?

Code:

```
gameIcon = pygame.image.load('path\\icon.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)
```

Thanks!

btw image size 200x200, the one that works is 512x512

Comment: Have you tried resizing the image to 512x512 (there are many online tools that can help you do this if you don't know how to). Secondly if that doesn't work it might be because the .extension is different than a png? hopefully you are able to find your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html):

```py
gameIcon = pygame.image.load('path\\icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

Comment: Hello! It still doesn't work after I put it in front of the display set mode.
my new code:

gameIcon = pygame.image.load('path\\icon.png')

pygame.display.set_icon(gameIcon)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1800, 1000))

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I resized the icon image to 512x512 and it works now. Thank you so much!